# Java Stocks Program Random Multi Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am doing a multi threading . I am unable to get the output i want. I have no compilation error . But I cant get the result I want. Can someone advise me ?

This is my Test program

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalShares = 0;
        double totalCost = 0.0;
        double profit = 0.0;
        int rand1 = 0;
        double rand2 = 0.0;
        Thread bt[] = new Thread[2];
        Thread st[] = new Thread[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try {

                bt[i].join();
                bt[i] = new BuyThread(rand1, rand2);
                bt[i].start();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try {
                st[i].join();
                st[i] = new SellThread(rand1, rand2);
                st[i].start();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Tracking of stock : FCS");

        System.out.println("Total shares now" + totalShares + "at total cost" + totalCost);

        System.out.printf("At$ 36.00 per share, profit is" + profit);
    }
}
```

This is my Stock Class

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stock {
    String name;
    int totalShares;
    double totalCost;
    double totalProfitLoss;


    public Stock(String theName) {
        name = theName;
        totalShares = 0;
        totalCost = 0.00;
        totalProfitLoss = 0.00;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getTotalShares() {
        return totalShares;
    }

    public double getTotalCost() {
        return totalCost;
    }

    public void buy(int shares, double pricePerShare) {
        totalShares += shares;
        totalCost += shares * pricePerShare;
    }

    public boolean sell(int shares, double pricePerShare) {
        double sellCost = shares * pricePerShare;

        if (shares <= totalShares && sellCost <= totalCost) {
            totalShares -= shares;
            totalCost -= sellCost;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public double profit() {
        totalProfitLoss = 36 * totalShares;
        return totalProfitLoss - totalCost;
    }
}
enter code here
```

This is my BuyThread program

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class BuyThread extends Thread {
    private int share;
    private double cost;
    private Stock stock;

    public BuyThread(int share, double cost) {
        this.share = share;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                Thread.sleep(100);
            Random randShare = new Random();
            int rand1 = randShare.nextInt(50) + 5; // value between 5 to 50
            double rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10 + 32) * 100.0) / 100.0; // value between 32.00 to 42.00
            stock.buy(rand1, rand2);
            System.out.println(rand1 + " shares has been brought at $" + rand2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is my SellThread

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class SellThread extends Thread {
    private int share;
    private double cost;
    private Stock stock;

    public SellThread(int share, double cost) {
        this.share = share;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
                Random randShare = new Random();
                int rand1 = randShare.nextInt(20) + 20;
                double rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 32 + 23) * 100.0) / 100.0;
                stock.sell(rand1, rand2);
                System.out.println(rand1 + "shares has been brought at $" + rand2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting a output like this (Which I have error running:

```
Tracking of Stock : FCS
8 shares has been brought at $37.61
Total shares now 8 at total cost $300.88
33 shares has been brought at $36.31
Total shares now 41 at total cost $1499.11  
17 shares has been sold at $42.67
Total shares now 24 at total cost $773.72
19 shares has been sold at $32.31
Total shares now 5 at total cost $159.83
31 shares has been brought at $33.85
Total shares now 36 at total cost $1209.18
28 shares has been brought at $36.37
Total shares now 64 at total cost $2227.54
20 shares has been brought at $35.49
Total shares now 84 at total cost $2937.34
At $36.00 per share, profit is $86.66
```

---

Ok , now i got my output but , everything doesnt seem to be in order. I tried for days and nights. Now I understand more about Multi Threading. How do i get the output as what i expected ? Can someone advise me which part did I do wrongly ?

This is my Test program

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{

public static void main (String[]args)
{
int totalShares = 0;
double totalCost = 0.0;
double totalProfitLoss = 0.0; 
int rand1 = 0;
double rand2 = 0.0;
Stock stock = new Stock("FCS",totalShares,totalCost,totalProfitLoss);

System.out.println ("Tracking of stock:  " +stock.name);
BuyThread bt = new BuyThread (rand1 , rand2 , stock);
SellThread st = new SellThread (rand1 , rand2 , stock);
bt.start();
st.start();

try
{
bt.join();
st.join();


System.out.println ("At$ 36.00 per share, profit is " + stock.getProfit(36.00));
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{}
}
}
```

This is my Stock Class

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Stock
{
String name;
int totalShares;
double totalCost; 
double totalProfitLoss;


public Stock(String name, int totalShares, double totalCost,double totalProfitLoss )
{
    this.name = name;
    this.totalShares = totalShares;
    this.totalCost = totalCost;
    this.totalProfitLoss = totalProfitLoss;
} 

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public double getTotalShares () 
{
    //totalShares++;
    return totalShares;
}
public double getTotalCost () 
{
   // totalCost++;
    return totalCost;
}
public double getTotalProfitLoss() 
{

    return totalProfitLoss;
}



public void buy(int shares, double pricePerShare)
{
    totalShares += shares;
    totalCost += shares * pricePerShare;
    System.out.println ("Total shares now at " +totalShares+ " at total cost $ " +totalCost);

}

public boolean sell(int shares, double pricePerShare) 
{
  double sellCost = shares * pricePerShare;


  if (shares >= totalShares || sellCost >= totalCost){

      return false;

    }
    else {
      totalShares -= shares;
      totalCost -= sellCost;

      System.out.println ("Total shares now at " +totalShares+ " at total cost $ "+totalCost);   

        return true;

    }

}

public double getProfit (double currentPrice)
{
    totalProfitLoss = currentPrice * totalShares;
    return totalProfitLoss - totalCost;
}

}
```

This is my BuyThread program

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class BuyThread extends Thread
{
private int rand1 ;
private double rand2;
private Stock stock;

public BuyThread (int rand1,double rand2,Stock stock)
{
this.rand1 = rand1 ;
this.rand2 = rand2 ;
this.stock = stock;
}

public void run()
{
for (int j = 0 ; j < 2; j++)
{
Random randShare = new Random ();
int rand1 = randShare.nextInt (50) + 5 ;
double rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10 + 32)* 100.0)/100.0 ;

stock.buy (rand1, rand2);
System.out.println (rand1+ " shares has been brought at $"+rand2) ;


try
{ sleep (50);
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{}
}
}
}
```

This is my SellThread

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class SellThread extends Thread
{
private int rand1 ;
private double rand2;
private Stock stock;

public SellThread (int rand1,double rand2,Stock stock)
{
this.rand1 = rand1 ;
this.rand2 = rand2 ;
this.stock = stock;
}

public void run()
{
for (int j = 0 ; j < 2; j++)
{
Random randShare = new Random ();
int rand1 = randShare.nextInt (20) + 20 ;
double rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 32 + 23)* 100.0)/100.0 ;

stock.sell (rand1 , rand2);
System.out.println (rand1+" shares has been sold at $"+rand2) ;


try
{
Thread.sleep(30);
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{}
}
}
}
```

I got this output

```
Tracking of stock:  FCS
Sell Total shares now at 13 at total cost $ 381.0999999999997
Buy Total shares now at 50 at total cost $ 1664.9999999999998
37 shares has been sold at $34.7
50 shares has been brought at $33.3
32 shares has been sold at $51.97
Buy Total shares now at 18 at total cost $ 555.1499999999996
5 shares has been brought at $34.81
At$ 36.00 per share, profit is 92.85000000000036
```

I am expecting a output like this (Which I have error running:

```
Tracking of Stock : FCS
8 shares has been brought at $37.61
Total shares now 8 at total cost $300.88
33 shares has been brought at $36.31
Total shares now 41 at total cost $1499.11  
17 shares has been sold at $42.67
Total shares now 24 at total cost $773.72
19 shares has been sold at $32.31
Total shares now 5 at total cost $159.83
31 shares has been brought at $33.85
Total shares now 36 at total cost $1209.18
28 shares has been brought at $36.37
Total shares now 64 at total cost $2227.54
20 shares has been brought at $35.49
Total shares now 84 at total cost $2937.34
At $36.00 per share, profit is $86.66
```

Comment: Well look at the types involved - the `share` and `cost` parameters are `int` and `double` respectively; `rand1` and `rand2` are `Random`. How did you expect that to work, and what do you *want* to happen? (Hint: look at the methods available on `Random`...)

Comment: Also note that using `double` to represent a financial value is a bad idea. Use `BigDecimal`, or an integer number of cents.

Comment: Also note that despite your tag, the problem here has nothing to do with multithreading.

Comment: and the title does not give any meaningful hints on your problem

Comment: This is part of my multi threading program , i didnt show all because i want to learn part by part before I put up all the program. Sorry that i tag wrongly.

Comment: I add in my complete multi threading , somewhere went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `rand1` and `rand2` which are of type `Random`.

Your `BuyThread` constructor is defined as taking an `int` and a `double`.

Comment: Am I right that under Test class, i need to declare rand1 as int and rand2 as double?